# Edit a command from PowerShell History, before it will be executed

Tags: powershell

If i use a command from the powershell history like `invoke-history -id 5` it will be executed as it is. 
Is there a way to edit the command before execute? 
I only found the `-confirm` option, but this will only show me the command before execution, but i don't found any possibiliy to edit it.

Thanks

Comment: You can use `(Get-History -Id 5).CommandLine` to get the string, but I'm not sure how you can add that output to the input buffer. Looking for a solution on that one

Comment: You are right, that command will output the command as a string. What i am searching for is something like the reverse-i-search in Linux/Bash. The found command in bash history is editable before execution.

Comment: I just answered with that in mind, the same functionality exists in PowerShell with `^R`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for a way to do this by inserting the output of `(Get-History -Id 5).CommandLine` into the input buffer, but I think that's the wrong way to go about this. You can do a [reverse search](http://woshub.com/powershell-commands-history/) of your command history by pressing `^R` (`CTRL + R`) and typing something from your history. The command will resolve the most recent command matching your input, but you can either continue to type, or press `^R` again to resolve the next most recent command.

This works just like the reverse search in Linux shells, but I'll explain below for the uninitiated.

---

If I ran the following yesterday:

```
ping www.google.com
```

And decided I want to run that again today, I would type the following keystrokes:

```
^R ping
```

Which will insert the most recent command conaining `ping`. If `ping www.google.com` isn't the most recent match, press `^R` again until you get the previous command you need.

---

This is less suitable in an automation scenario, but is useful when working with the terminal interactively. If you need to transform a previous command programmatically, you can get the output of `(Get-History -Id 5).CommandLine` and transform the resulting string accordingly before executing with the call `&` operator.

Comment: I double facepalm myself. ```^R``` Thats exactly the same way like in Linux/Bash. Thank you :)

Comment: I remember when I found out powershell supported reverse search like *sh. I was like "WHAT NO WAY"